# Поиск группы в строке состоящий только из 3 нулей подряд

Tags: python, строки

У меня считает только те группы ,у которых пробелы с обоих сторон,но ставить пробел в начале нельзя,прога должна понимать что это тоже нужная группа
Вот мой код:

```
str =input("Введите строку=> ")
sub=" 000 ";
print ("str.count(000) : ", str.count(sub))
```

Comment: `sub = "000"` ?

Comment: Группа должна быть только из 3х нулей " 000 ",а если в sub написать ,как у вас,то и "1000" ,и "0001" будет считать

Comment: извините в начале не понял суть задания

Comment: Ничего,спасибо ,что помогли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = input()
x = 0
for i in text.split():
    if i == "000":
        x += 1
print(x)
```